# Python - replace multiple characters without .replace()

Tags: python, replace

The task is to transform any string into any string without built-in `.replace()`. I failed because I forgot that technically space is also a string character. Firstly I transformed this string into the list, but now I see I did it unnecessarily. However, it still doesn't work.

1. I can replace "cat" into "dog"
2. I can replace "c" into "dog"

I can't replace "a cat" into "a dog".

I tried with `lambda` or `zip`, but I don't really know how to do it. Do you have any clue?

```
string = "Alice has a cat, a cat has Alice."
old = "a cat"
new = "a dog"

def rplstr(string,old,new):
    """ docstring"""

    result = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == old:
            i = new
        result += i
    return result

print rplstr(string, old, new)
```

Comment: did you try `re.sub`?

Comment: Hmm... given strings are immutable, really the assignment doesn't make sense since you could just `return new`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can step through the string, one character at a time, and test to see if it matches with the first character of your `old` string.  If it matches, keep a reference to the index, then continue stepping through the characters, now trying to match against the 2nd char of `old`.  Keep going until you match the entire `old` string.  If the full match succeeds, use the index of the first character match and the length of the `old` string to create a new string with the `new` string inserted into it.

```
def replstr(orig, old, new):
    i = 0
    output = ''
    temp = ''
    for c in orig:
        if c == old[i]:
            i += 1
            temp += c
        else:
            i = 0
            if temp:
                output += temp
                temp = ''
            output += c
        if len(temp) == len(old):
            output += new
            temp = ''
            i = 0
    else:
        if temp:
            output += temp
```

Comment: >>>Alice hasa a dogt, a dog hasa aAalaiacaea.a

That's what I have, but probably it's just the matter of a few small things in the code. A cat was changed into a dog. I'll read your code few times. Thank you.

Comment: @TomWojcik Ah, yes, I missed a line.  Updated.

Answer (score 5):

This solution avoids string concatenation which can be less efficient. It creates a list of segments to join together at the end:

```
string = "Alice has a cat, a cat has Alice."
old = "a cat"
new = "a dog"

def rplstr(string, old, new):
    """ docstring"""

    output = []
    index = 0

    while True:
        next = string.find(old, index)

        if next == -1:
            output.append(string[index:])
            return ''.join(output)
        else:
            output.append(string[index:next])
            output.append(new)
            index = next + len(old)

print rplstr(string, old, new)
```

Giving:

```
Alice has a dog, a dog has Alice.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with slices:

```
def rplstr(string, old, new):
    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        if old == string[i:i+len(old)]:
            string = string[:i] + new + string[i+len(old):]
    return string
```

Comment: I believe if the `new` string is longer than the `old` string, then letters on the end of the string won't get tested.  Or if the `new` string contains the `old` string.

Comment: You, sir, know how to code. Thank you. Works perfect and it's relatively simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a simple and tiny way by using regular expressions.

```
import re

my_string = "Alice has a cat, a cat has Alice."
new_string = re.sub(r'a cat', 'a dog', my_string)
print new_string
```

Comment: Indeed, it does work but my tutor said that we cannot use any built-in methods, nor regular expressions.